# Count the number of corners of a polygon

Tags: arcobjects

How can I automatically count the number of corners that has a polygon using VBA and ArcObjects?

Comment: Wouldn't the count of corners be the same as the count of points (less one, since the start and end points are the same)? Obviously a "corner" in this case may not be very apparent to the eye; I guess it depends upon what you mean by corner.

Comment: Although I managed to count the number of points of each polygon the problem is that even a polygon may be approximately rectangular actually has more than four points because of the digitization process i.e. sometimes an approximate straight line consists of more than 2 points. How can I ignore the intermmediate points? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Strictly speaking, the number of corners, is one less than the number of vertices in the polygon.

You should cast the geometry (IPolygon) to IPointCollection.
The IPointCollection.Pointcount property gives you the number of vertices.

Just subtract one to get the number of corners.

Comment: Good idea; but the number of vertices e.g. saying a rectangle polygon has the same number of corners (i.e. points) with the number of vertices and not one less. Isn't it?

Comment: No, a rectangle has 5 pairs of points, the start and end being the same, so it has 4 corners.

Comment: A square polygon can have 5 vertices - one for the start, 3 for each point on the square and one for the end.  So the start and end vertex equal each other.  But that's not always the case.  You'll need to compare start and end vertex, if they are the same then minus one.  Also you'll need to code for donut and multipart polygons if they exist in the dataset.

Comment: @Rob Good point.  The general formula is to subtract the number of rings from the count of nodes.  This simultaneously takes care of polygons with multiple connected components and of multiply-connected polygons (those with "holes").

Comment: I would think also looking for an angle less than 180 would also be needed to account for psuedo nodes.

Comment: How many corners does a circular polygon have?

Comment: A square polygon can have many more than 5 points (1st = last argument aside) if the segments forming the polygon have been densified.

Comment: This is all a bit crazy now; there are no circular polygons, there are circles, and polygons: A polygon is a plane figure with at least three straight sides.  A square can't be more than 4 vertices, it is no longer a square if it has more, regardless if it has been densified; the mathematical defintion of a square is having four equal sides and four right angles and is a specific case of a regular polygon.  A polygon is 'a number of coplanar line segments, each connected end to end to form a closed shape'.  A square has 4 vertices, a circle has no coplanar line segments.

Comment: Hairy, has clarify these simple issues very well!

Comment: @Hairy makes excellent points.  The comments by @Kirk and @Dan remind us, though, that there's more than geometry involved here.  We need to bear in mind the difference between a *geometric object* and its *representation in the GIS.*  Taking "polygon," "square," etc. in their geometric senses leads to Hairy's clarification.  But Dan points out a geometric square might have a representation with more than four nodes (plus one wrap-around node); and Kirk, with his probing question, reminds us that in many GIS contexts even a "circle" is of the same type as a "polygon."

Comment: Agreed completely.  In GML 2.1, even the Ordinance Survey have a representation of a circle as a multi vertice polygon, but for me, this is no longer a circle, but a representation of a circle (we cna call these hacks ;) ) and we have to ensure we can distinguish between the two.